# How to pass a value from ngOnInit to function

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I'm wondering how can I pass a value from ngOnInit to function at the same component.

Here is my example. I get data from API, to display context of my page. Later when I click the button I would like to use that data, but in console.log I get undefined. How's that undefined since data was already loaded and displayed on my page.

```
...
 clientId1;
 clientId2;
 clientNote;
 errorMsg;

 ngOnInit() {
    this.clientId1 = this.route.parent.snapshot.paramMap.get('userId1');
    this.clientId2 = this.getMethodClientId2();
  }

  getMethodClientId2(): void {
    this.userService.getUser().subscribe(
      (data) => {
        this.clientNote = data.ClientNotes;
      },
      (error) => (this.errorMsg = error)
    );
  }


  postMethodOnClick() {
    console.log(this.clientId1);
    console.log(this.clientId2);
}
...
```

Comment: Please create a [small demo](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) for this using [codesandbox.io](https://codesandbox.io/) to show the issue happening. You can use a fake API call to show the demo.

Comment: The `getMethodClientId2()` method does not return anything, so how do you expect `console.log(this.clientId2)` to show anything else but `undefined` :)?

Comment: Are you getting undefined for both the console logs?

Comment: I don't see where clientId2 is being set.  Is it suppose to be set in getMethodClientId2()?

Comment: Have a look at [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Comment: that said `getMethodClientId2` never returns anything so I'm not clear what you're expecting `this.clientId2 = this.getMethodClientId2();` to do or what you expect `this.clientId2` to contain?

Answer (score 2):

There are multiple issues here.

1. The variable `clientNote` is assigned value asynchronously. So if you were to access the data outside the subscription, you have no context of whether the data is assigned or not.
2. `clientId2` variable does not hold the possible cliend ID, it holds nothing at the moment. Judging by the names of your function, I believe you were trying to do this

```js
 ngOnInit() {
    this.clientId1 = this.route.parent.snapshot.paramMap.get('userId1');
    this.getMethodClientId2();    // <-- don't assign here, you aren't returning anything from the asynchronous function
  }

  getMethodClientId2(): void {
    this.userService.getUser().subscribe(
      (data) => {
        this.clientNote = data.ClientNotes;
        this.clientId2 = data.ClientId;  // <-- I assume the property is called `ClientId`.
      },
      (error) => (this.errorMsg = error)
    );
  }
```

Again, variable `this.clientId2` is assigned asynchronously, so if you were to call the function `postMethodOnClick()` before the values are assigned, the console log will still be `undefined`.

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14220321/6513921) for more info on how to access async data.